How to copy and run tests from dependencies
I attach my module with tests as a dependency to another project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.qwep</groupId>
    <artifactId>vendor-nexus</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.qwep</groupId>
    <artifactId>vendor-nexus</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

I set up copying, which is successful and when mvn clean install actually gets into the *target/test classes folder.
screenshot 1
screenshot 2
But only the tests from the project itself are started, the copied ones are not. I have not played around with the maven-surefire-plugin configuration - they do not start, they are just ignored.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <dependenciesToScan>
            <dependency>ru.qwep.vendoradapter</dependency>
        </dependenciesToScan>

        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>
                ${project.build.directory}/test-classes/ru/qwep/vendoradapter
            </additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>

        <testSourceDirectory>
            ${project.build.directory}/test-classes/ru/qwep/vendoradapter
        </testSourceDirectory>

        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>

    </configuration>
</plugin>

This is how I build my artifact, if it helps to identify the problem.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>

            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>test-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>tests</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <executions>
       
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>sources</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
     
        <execution>
            <id>attach-test-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>

<!--                <goal>test-jar</goal>-->
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>test-sources</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


I removed your second question. You should only ask one question per question.

Why do you want to copy tests from somewhere else?

@J Fabian Meier
Because I need to run tests connected as dependency, at build time, but I don't know how to do that without copying to the tests folder in target

First you should configure maven-surefire-plugin accordingly: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan second why do you have configured the maven-sources-plugin?

@NikitaSerzhevskiy Why don't you just copy or move the source of the tests to the project that you want to test?

the problem was in the adapter-side version of the test library: so no plugins or dependencies could start tests there, they just didn't see them.
